# How to get the discord id of users who have reacted to a specific message discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like to grab the `id` of users who have reacted to a specific message and push them to the variable `players`, I've `console.log()` multiple things searching for a solution, used google, and asked friends, which was not successful. I hope that I can find someone with enough experience to help me find an answer or another question with an answer to this small problem I have.

```js
let players = [message.author.id]
message.react('')
const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === ''
message.awaitReactions(filter, { time: 20000 })
       .then(collected => {
           console.log(collected.user.id)
           players.push(collected.user.id)
        })
       .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: When you log ``collected.user.id``, does it print the id?

Comment: No, it does not, it prints undefined.

Comment: I'm not sure what to do next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`awaitReactions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=awaitReactions) returns a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) of [`MessageReaction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction)s. Therefore `collected.user` will be undefined.

You'll have to get the first [`MessageReaction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction) from the [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) and access its [`users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction?scrollTo=users) property, filtering the bot's ID out.

---

```js
// Creating a filter.
const Filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === "";

// Reacting to the message.
await message.react("");

// Awaiting reactions.
message.awaitReactions(Filter, { time: 6000 }).then((collected) => {
    const reaction = collected.first();

    // Making sure that at least one user reacted to the message
    if (reaction) {
        const players = reaction.users.cache.filter((user) => user.id !== client.user.id);

        console.log(`Users that reacted: ${players.map((user) => user.username).join(", ")}`);
    } else {
        console.log("No one reacted to this message.");
    }
});
```

---

If you are getting an error such as `The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method.` you'll have to make your method async.

Example:

```js
client.on("message", async (message) => {
    // Code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this documentation: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#reacting-in-order

```
const userReactions = message.reactions.cache.filter(reaction => reaction.users.cache.has(userId));
try {
    for (const reaction of userReactions.values()) {
        await reaction.users.remove(userId);
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to remove reactions.');
}
```

You can use this example but instead of removing the userId you can do something along the lines of:

```
const userReactions = message.reactions.cache.filter(reaction => reaction.users.cache.has(userId));
try {
    players.push(userId)
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to push reaction');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === ''
    message.awaitReactions(filter, { time: 20000 })
    .then(collected => {
       collected.first().users.cache.forEach(u => players.push(u.id))
    })
    .catch(console.error);
```

I couldn’t test it. Please tell me any errors you may have.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks!
(I tested both answers so if others pass by to look for an answer it will be somewhat easier for them)

Comment: You can click the check mark if it answers it the best